# Trying to get property of non-object when getting role for user

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have created a relationship between User and Role and it is like One User Belongs To a Role

```
public function role(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
}
```

Now I am trying to access the user role and it is throwing this error

**Error**:

> Trying to get property of non-object

**Code For getting User Role:**

```
@foreach($users as $user)
        <tr role="row" class="odd">
            <td>{!! $user->role->name !!}</td>
        </tr>
@endforeach
```

**Tables Schema :**

**Users**:
id,
role_id,
name,
email

**Role**:
id,
name

I test it in **Tinker** it is working perfect but when I launched it in browser it throws that error.

Comment: I don't see any problem in your code. Show us where you define `$users`, whole `User` class and `Role` class.

Comment: How are you sending $users to view? Anyway you'll want to eager-load the role relationship to avoid doing 1+n queries inside the @foreach loop.

Comment: did you used get() method ? or toArray() method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you trying to `$user->role->name` and get `Trying to get property of non-object` perhaps you could check if there is a user without role_id = null in table `Users`.

Answer (score 0):

Set you user role. It happened to me, and I set the user role from my admin console and I was able to use

```
  public function index(Request $request){
        //error_log($request->user());

        return redirect()->route($request->user()->role);
    }
```

I think the user or role is null or has not been set that is why

Answer (score -4):

You can write
`

```
@foreach($users as $user)
        <tr role="row" class="odd">
           @foreach($user->role as $r)
             <td>{{ $r->name }}</td>
           @endforeach`
        </tr>
@endforeach
```

`
Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: `$user->role` can return just one item (not a collection) because it's defined through `belongsTo` method which is a one-to-many relationship.